# Error in converting decimal to float in a SqlDataRecord

Tags: c#, type-conversion, .net-4.5

I have a SqlMetaData array defined as:

```
SqlMetaData[] _TvpSchema = new SqlMetaData[]{
     new SqlMetaData("Duration", SqlDbType.Float)
};
```

And SqlDataRecord for it as :

```
SqlDataRecord _DataRecord = new SqlDataRecord(_TvpSchema);
```

And filling this record as:

```
_DataRecord.SetFloat(4, (float)obj.Duration);
```

Where obj.Duration is **decimal type** and has value as **0**. I am getting Exception of **Invalid Cast** at the above line. I tried **Convert.ToSingle** also, but got the same error. What I might be doing wrong in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SQL `Float` is a .Net `double` [according to `SqlDbType` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx). If you really need to use a .Net `float`, use the SQL `Real` type, otherwise, just use `SetDouble` and cast your `decimal` to `double`.